# If I create a provision profile with the agent developer, the device can debug with the profile?

Tags: iphone, debugging, device, profile

If create two provision profiles, one for admin developer, another for agent developer, but when I choose the profile to debug the app in device, only profile for admin developer can be selected, the profile for agent developer is gray(can't be selected). I doubt about that whether the device can't debug app with agent developer profile?

Comment: It is greyed out because bundle Id of your app doesn't match with the bundle Id of agent developer. Also apart from that there could be the other reason where private key is missing.

Comment: Forget to say that the bundle is correct and the private is in the keychain also it is not expired.